# Filter an elasticsearch result after an aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have this elasticsearch query that get every x-locations for which the number of documents (with timestamp gte 1 month ago) is greater than 5000. I'm also able to get the most recent data timestamp for each of these x-locations.

Is it possible to add an additional filter at the end of the query, in order to ignore all x-locations for which the most recent timestamp is older than 2 days ago?

The query:

```
GET /mypattern-*/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {"method": "GET"}},
                {
                    "range": {
                        "timestamp": {
                            "gte": "now-1M"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "location_terms": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "x-location.keyword",
                "min_doc_count": 500,
                "size": 1000,
                "order": {
                    "recent_timestamp": "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "recent_timestamp": {
                    "max": {
                        "field": "timestamp"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you need to filter them after? You can filter documents before: in your range: ```"range": {  "timestamp": { "gte": "now-1M", "lt": "now-1d"}}```

Comment: I don't want data that is lower than 1d ago. I want to keep the x-location values for which max(timestamp) is gte (now-1d)

Comment: Ah sorry, read it wrong. In this case you probably can use pipeline bucket selector https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.5/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html

Comment: Did you try to use filter aggregation? You can copy the same aggregation inside the filter aggregation by adding your range aggregation as 2 days ago?